# Want to extend private class to change config for my use

Tags: ios, swift, class, overriding

I have a class A, it is general template to be extended to use. I dont know how to extension ClassA and change something for me to use.

PS: I would like to remove view1 and change the view backgroundColor (only for my page). Please help

```
class A {
 private let view1 = UIView()

 view.backgroundColor = .red
 view.addSubview(view1)
}
```

Comment: Do you wanna extend the class A or you wanna inherit this class in another class?

Comment: inherit this class. but something changed for my use

Comment: It's not clear how you want to extend the class and the code you have posted doesn't compile so it doesn't help much. You say you want to remove a property so maybe the best solution is to create a completely new class?

Comment: I would like to inherit ClassA (Use whole class), but i just want to apply in my page with some changes

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access private variable if you inherit :

```
class A {
     let view1 = UIView()
     view.backgroundColor = .red
     view.addSubview(view1)
    }
    
    
    class B: A {
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view1.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Comment: but how can call modify method and only affect my page only. there are private let, can i access directly?

Comment: Check the updated answer